# Как присвоить заново id без автоинкремента?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица в `ms sql`, назовем ее `content`. Есть 3 столбца (`id`, `com1`, `com2`). В таблице не подключен автоинкремент и не будет подключен.

В результате добавление и удаления строк появилась необходимость заново пронумеровать все строки, то есть присвоить `id` 1, 2, 3, 4 и так далее, не подключая автоинкремент. Есть ли возможность это сделать запросом `ms sql`?

Comment: Можно сделать update на основе row_number, если нужно сохранить порядок

Answer (score 0):

Можете создать последовательность (https://sql-ex.ru/blogs/?/ModernizaciJa_vashego_koda_T-SQL_obekt_Sequence.html):

```
CREATE sequence seq1 start
    WITH 1 increment BY 1;
```

а потом обновить:

```
update content set id= NEXT value FOR seq1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Пронумеруйте на основе старых id и сделайте апдейт на основе селекта:

```
update x
set id = new_id
from (
    select id, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) AS new_id from content
    ) x
```